# Is it possible to restore a Redshift database from snapshot?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I want to restore a Redshift DB from one cluster to another. Is it possible?

Comment: what did u try?

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka I tried to look for such an option in the "Restore from snapshot" UI in the Redshift console and also in boto3 docs, but I didn't find anything

Comment: What is the situation in which you find yourself? Did you lose some data that you now wish to restore? Is it a whole database, or just a table?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I want to create a pre-prod environment which will be identical to the production cluster and will be recreated every night. The issue is that I don't want the redshift version to be updated since there's a bug in the queries rewriter which affects us. The production version is suspended so it won't be updated and I want the same to be in the pre-prod but it will be created with the latest (or trailing) version as default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Amazon Redshift snapshots - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/working-with-snapshots.html):

> When you restore from a snapshot, Amazon Redshift creates a new cluster and makes the new cluster available before all of the data is loaded, so you can begin querying the new cluster immediately.

Thus, a **new cluster** is always created from the snapshot. It is *not* possible to restore a snapshot to an *existing* cluster.

You would need to create a new cluster, then *somehow* migrate your desired database/schema/tables to the existing cluster.